# R rcppbugs: how to disable the ouput of estimated values

Tags: r, optimization

I'm now using rcppbugs to optimize parameters of an ecosystem model. The situation is that my observed data is a very long time series and it needs at least 10,000 iterations. Since the `run.model()` outputs the estimated values (here **y.hat**) at every time, this causes a big problem, e.g.:

```
List of 6
 $ factor1 : num [1:2] 0.921 0.921
 $ factor2 : num [1:2] 2 2
 $ factor3 : num [1:2] 0.954 0.954
 $ tau.y   : num [1:2] 0.17 0.17
 $ y.hat   : num [1:2, 1:70176] 0.139 0.139 0.138 0.138 0.136 ...
 $ y.lik   : NULL
 - attr(*, "acceptance.ratio")= num 0
```

Obviously it is difficult to save y.hat every time but meanwhile I need to record all factor1, factor2 and factor3 values. Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I see no `message`, `print` or `cat` statements in the function, which means the C++ code is printing. Have you tried `capture.output()` to suppress the output?

Comment: Thanks Roman. It works in R but still y.hat will be output in C++ code. I wonder if this will have any influence. My memory is 4 GB, so if I iterate the model by 10,000 times, will the C++ code crash? I'm trying revising the C++ source code but it costs quite a lot of time.

Comment: `capture.output` will only "suppress" printing. All calculations are still being done and returned to the variable you use to save the result. I am not familiar with this project and I can't tell about how C++ code will behave.

Comment: I agree with above. For me it is better to revise the source code, I think. Thanks anyway, Roman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The y.hat variable is outputted by `getHistory()` function in rcppbugs C++ source code. Thus, it is enough to modify this function to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

If printing is done through R's `message` or `warning`, you can use `suppressMessages` and `suppressWarnings`, respectively. If output is produced using `cat`, `print` or is sent to "std out" from a C/C++/Fortran function, you can use `capture.output`.